# how to resize images in Black Berry according to the width and height of the display screen?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-os6

How can I re-size the image stored in resource folder using code according to the display width and height  of blackberry screen?

Comment: before posting over here try to search for similar posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create a encoded image like this

```
 EncodedImage ei = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("res/helpscreen.png");
```

then pass this encoded image to the below function

```
EncodedImage ei1= scaleImage(ei,reqWidth,requiredHeight);


 public EncodedImage scaleImage(EncodedImage source, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight) 
    {  
        int currentWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getWidth());  
        int requiredWidthFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredWidth);  
        int scaleXFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentWidthFixed32, requiredWidthFixed32);  
        int currentHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(source.getHeight());  
        int requiredHeightFixed32 = Fixed32.toFP(requiredHeight);  
        int scaleYFixed32 = Fixed32.div(currentHeightFixed32, requiredHeightFixed32);  
        return source.scaleImage32(scaleXFixed32, scaleYFixed32);  
    }
```

this will give you a encoded image. then convert it to Bitmap using

```
        BitmapField logoBitmap = new BitmapField(ei1.getBitmap());
```

Answer (score 0):

To scale a `Bitmap` image try `Bitmap.scaleInto(...)`. [API Link.](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#scaleInto%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap,%20int,%20int%29)

```
Bitmap targetBm = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
srcBitmap.scaleInto(targetBm, Bitmap.FILTER_BILINEAR, Bitmap.SCALE_STRETCH);
```